# What is up with my plant?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, aloe

I got this plant off my grandad last year and think it’s some kind of aloe Vera plant but I’m really not quite sure. Last week I noticed the bottom leaf becoming brown and crispy and the leaf above not being too healthy either. As I’m very new to plant keeping could somebody tell me what’s wrong is it and how I can fixed it?

Thanks a bunch

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello Katey & Welcome, The pictures will not enlarge, so they need to be a little closer to get a good look.We also need more information, like How do you decide when to water? Are there holes in the bottom of the pot?  What kind of soil is planted in? Amount of sunlight does it get? As much information as you can think of. My best guess.  The plant lost an older leaf, its natural. At some point an aloe loose lower leaves in the process they absorb the water from the leaf.  It is also not uncommon to for a plant to do a second shortly after the first. But, need more info

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply! I tried to upload the photos but had to resize them for the website. I usually water it very little once a week but went away over Christmas so I got out of schedule. It’s in a little plant pot with holes in the bottom in a succulent soil and is kept under a velux window so gets around 8 hours of sunlight.

Answer (score 2):

Pull these off the from the stalk plant , instead of cutting them.

At some point the lower leaves die off, getting crispy and brown.

If any of the bad ones are left on the stem they  could rot and may harm your plant.

Also as you already know this plant is drought tolerant, so deffo take it easy with the water  :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I’ll get them removed right away 

Comment: Your welcome :) also check out how to propagate this plant! It has many excellent and beneficial uses. So you should propagate and share it :)